# Matrix of empty tables in R

Tags: r, matrix, count, initialization

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences in many vectors and store them in a matrix in R. For example, I'd like entries in the matrix `a` such as `a[[1]]`, `a[[2]]`, etc. to contain counts of the number of 7's, 8's, and 9's in a set of vectors. I know I can produce the counts using `table(factor(x, levels=7:9))`, where `x` is one of the vectors in the set, but I'd like to pre-allocate the matrix with empty tables because I have to sometimes add on to the previous table that already exists in one of the matrix entries. For example if `a[[10]]` currently equals `[3 3 1]` and, in a new `x` (which somehow corresponds to the tenth entry in `a`), I count `[1 0 1]`, I'd like `a[[10]]` to be updated to `[4 3 2]`. This can be done in one line by just adding the new counts to the previous value, but I can't do this the first time I count in an `x` corresponding to `a[[10]]` unless I've pre-allocated the matrix entry to contain 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this simply by preceding my code with a check for if `a[[i]]` is `null`. If so, then I did `a[[i]] = table(factor(0, levels=7:9))`.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it seems like the 'a' `list` have `vector`s with different `unique` elements.  We can change the `vector` class to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` `sort`ed elements from the `unlist`ed 'a'.

```
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(a)))
a1 <- lapply(a, function(x) factor(x, levels = lvls))
```

When we apply the `table`, the levels will be the same in this way

```
lapply(a1, table)
```

Or we can apply the `table` once after converting the `list` to a `data.frame`

```
table(stack(setNames(a1, seq_along(a1)))[2:1])
```

---

The idea is to create the elements in the same `order`.  So, if the previous entries are also created based on the same `level` order, we can do the summation by just `+`.